# Cant Disable Lazy Loading and Proxy Creation on DbContext EFCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to disable lazy Loading on EntityFramework.Core

In my previous code I have done the following :

```
  public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

but now using the new ef 7 i cant find any option to do so

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        //should have been in the options
    }
```

Comment: Based on some research it looks like there is no lazy loading for the EF 7

Comment: Yeah which is upsetting for me

Answer (score 3):

As of 2019 Lazy Loading is supported but not enabled by default, so there is nothing that you need to do still.

Comment: Is there a way to enable it? Can't really find the option or Configuration anywhere.

Comment: Add the following nuget package and look up how to enable https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

Answer (score 1):

Per the [current documentation](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying/related-data.html) on 'Loading Related Data':

> **Lazy loading is not yet supported by EF Core.** You can view the [lazy loading item on our backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797) to track this feature.

So, your answer: do nothing.

Comment: I Also found out that there is no DbSet.Find() method... So Sad About their release then

Comment: @EduCielo You can always write your own `Find(...)` method as an Extension method.

Comment: The Good ole Find method is there these days

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is disabled LazyLoading try:
this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;